# Mongo, queries difference

Tags: mongodb

Are there any differences between queries

```
db.getCollection("cart").find(
    {
        "$and" : [
            {"$text":{"$search":"\"One\""}},
            {"user_id":1},
            {"shop_id":1},
            {"deleted":false},
        ]
    }
).sort({"score":{"$meta":"textScore"}, "updated_at":-1}).limit(12)
```

and

```
db.getCollection("cart").find(
    {
        "$text":{"$search":"\"One\""},
        "user_id":1,
        "shop_id":1,
        "deleted":false,
    }
).sort({"score":{"$meta":"textScore"}, "updated_at":-1}).limit(12)
```

I thought that the result of both queries must be the same, but it's not, both queries return the same data but in a different order, can someone explain to me why?

Comment: I can only guess. Are there documents with identical textScore? Are the same indexes being used (you can try to include `$meta: "indexKey"` and `$meta: "textScore"` in your result documents)`?

Comment: collection has only one text index, so it can't be different indexes. I do not know about the score, is there a way to check? but it returns the same documents and if the scores are different can I control/change it somehow?

Comment: I'll try tun explain to see if there are any diffs

Comment: explain showing identical execution plan and stats...

Comment: Does [this official example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-field) answer your question?

Comment: @ray not sure I understand, I do not have `$or` operator in my query, all should be the same. The issue here is that I have multiple apps and each app has its own Mongo driver, in one app driver transforms the query builder to query with `$and` and the other without, so in the end I have the result in a different order.

Comment: also regarding the link, as I mentioned it returns the same document, in my case same 12 documents, but in a different order, so selecting part doing the same, something wrong with sorting part

Comment: Can you post the sample data that show different sort order?

Answer (score 0):

The section referenced below from MangoDB manual may help you to continue your analysis and find out the exact reason.

The relevant points from the document listed:

1. **The conditionals given in an array are treated differently**

> When you query values in arrays, Atlas Search doesn't alter the score of the matching results based on the number of values inside the array that matched the query. The score would be the same as a single match regardless of the number of matches inside an array.

2. **The score with respect to each document can be brought into the result and analyse your case more closely.**

   *"$project": {"score": { "$meta": "searchScore" }}*
3. **Furthermore, score-breakup may also be brought against each document and extend your analysis.**

   *{ "$project": { "scoreDetails": { "$meta": "searchScoreDetails" }}*

[Score the Documents in the Results](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/scoring/#:%7E:text=Score%20the%20Documents%20in%20the%20Results)

Thanks
WeDoTheBest4You